# Issue extracting "mentions" from Twitter data using regex

Tags: regex, pandas

I am trying to extract the mentions in a Tweet from Twitter i.e. `@Google` or `@Apple`.

This is my code so far to extract the mentions from a column and then create another column with the mentions.

```
df_bdtu['mentions'] = df_bdtu['tweet_text'].str.findall('(?:^|\s)[＠ @]{1}([^\s#<>[\]|{}]+)')
```

It works mostly but I am facing some issues with some edge cases for example take this Tweet:

```
Check out @Dreams_n_Songs and give them a follow! I can't recommend their hoodies enough!Shop now  …
```

The mentions stored in the `mentions` column below which is incorrect as it includes the emoji for some reason.

```
['Dreams_n_Songs', '…']
```

Another issue is when there is a `.` before the mentions such as this example:

```
.@ChelseaFC, @FCBayern, @VfL_Wolfsburg and more are among the latest names to be confirmed at -…
```

The mentions that are produced do not include the first mention.

```
[FCBayern,, VfL_Wolfsburg]
```

How would I fix the regex for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
[＠@]([^][\s#<>|{}]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UAEOMq/2). So, remove `(?:\s|^)` that requires either start of string or a whitespace at the start of a match, and you need to remove a literal space from the `[＠ @]` character class.

In Pandas code, you can use it like this:

```py
df_bdtu['mentions'] = df_bdtu['tweet_text'].str.findall(r'[＠@]([^][\s#<>|{}]+)')
```

Mind the `r'...'` raw string literal notation.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, appreciate the detailed answer as well. Will accept the answer when I am allowed to.